# mysql if not null, 0 or ""

Tags: mysql, isnull

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table WHERE id IN ('21') 
   AND (content_id IS NULL OR content_id = 0 OR content_id = '')
```

Is there a shorter way of writing this condition.

I have a int() column that could be either: NULL, 0 or EMPTY.

Comment: A nullable int column can be either an int or NULL - it can't be an empty string.

Comment: is content_id a int column or a varchar column? if it's an int column there's no need to check if content_id='' so I think I'll delete my answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `IFNULL` function in MySQL.

```
select ____
  from tbl
 where IFNULL(content_id, 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the shorter way is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE id IN ('21')
      AND COALESCE(content_id IN ('0', ''), 1)
```

`content_id IN ('0', '')` may assume these values:

- **True** if `content_id` is either `'0'` or `''`
- **Null** if `content_id IS Null`
- **False** otherwise.

If it's `Null`, COALESCE will return `1` here, which is equivalent to `True`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('21') 
AND COALESCE(content_id,0) =0;
```

Comment: Coalesce is mobile to all RDBMS platforms. Check here for a comparison of [SQL ISNULL(), NVL(), IFNULL() and COALESCE() Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)